# why ajax post method return empty alert box when i tried to return data from controller file in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

This is my ajax function

```
$(function(){
       $("#myform").submit(function(){ //i want to get data from my form after submittingit
         dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
         alert(dataString);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/customer/viewCustomerData",
           data: dataString,

       success: function(data){
           alert(data);
       }

     });

     return false;  

  });
   });
```

this is my controller class function

```
function viewCustomerData(){

    if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    return 'name';
    }
 else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

other thing is i tried to alert data string taken from form serialize, but it also empty. I want to return data set from database after sending key word from javascript file. i tried if the javascript file connect correctly with my controller function. so i tried to return some value and display it using alert box. but it gives empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant alert `$("#myform").serialize();` because this is an object instead of alert it try `console.log($("#myform").serialize();)`
then open browser console and see what is printed

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/customer/viewCustomerData",
       data: dataString,
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: i tried. nothing display in console. only show " " for form serialize

Answer (score 1):

This is better way to submit a form with ajax

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myform", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/customer/viewCustomerData"
        type: "POST",            
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
           alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it. but it's not working. what i suppose to do is i want to send values from input fields to database via ajax post method. and return relevant data row from database to table in view file.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function(){
   $("#myform").submit(function(){
     dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
     alert(dataString);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/customer/viewCustomerData",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       datatype: 'json',
       success: function(data){
           alert(data.result);
       }
     });
   });
});
```

in controller

```
function viewCustomerData(){

    if($this->input->post('name'){
        $result = $this->input->post('name');
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));

}
```